# Numbering equation for each custom section

Tags: equations

I have created an environment named `hwp` with custom headers and footers that works otherwise very much like the native section environment, in which I can set equations, add figures, etc. What I would like to do is to use the `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` for `hwp`. In other words, the numbering of equations should be reset whenever a new `hwp` is created.

As it appears that I have to work around the `\numberwithin` command, I have been working on setting up my own counter that would serve the purpose, yet to no avail. The following is the code related to my goal. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
\newcounter{hwpcounter}
\newcounter{eqcounter}
\renewcommand{\theeqcounter}{\addtocounter{eqcounter}{1}}

\newenvironment{hwp}[1][Prob \arabic{hwpcounter}]
{
    \stepcounter{hwpcounter}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{hwpcounter}.\theeqcounter}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I provided a dummy definition for the `hwp` environment, since the one given in the question is not complete:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{hwpcounter}

\newenvironment{hwp}[1][Prob~\arabic{hwpcounter}]
  {\refstepcounter{hwpcounter}\par#1\par\nobreak}
  {\par}

\numberwithin{equation}{hwpcounter}

\begin{document}

\begin{hwp}
test
\begin{equation}
a=b.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a=b.
\end{equation}
\end{hwp}

\begin{hwp}
test
\begin{equation}
a=b.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a=b.
\end{equation}
\end{hwp}

\end{document}
```

[image]